# SQL Server trigger (update or insert with inner join problem)

Tags: sql-server, trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[killertrigg]
   ON  [dbo].[tbl_pvporderview]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF (UPDATE([Kill]))
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT  killer(serial,[Kill])
    SELECT i.serial,i.[Kill] FROM inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d
    ON i.serial = d.serial 
    AND i.[Kill] <> d.[Kill] AND i.[Kill] > 0;
END
```

However how would I go if I would want it to update if the serial already exist in the `killer` table. Could do update first and if it returns rowcount 0/null then do insert but I got stuck   WHERE - since I can't use `i.serial = d.serial` to compare there.

Comment: Can you not use the INSERTED table?

Comment: inserted and deleted are sql special tables not real tables in my db (stores deleted and insert values before query is actually run or something like that).

Comment: Update what to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about changing the trigger to a BEFORE UPDATE? That way you can check the values before any action has taken place.

**EDIT**

OK so I think I understand what you are trying to do. How about this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[killertrigg]
   ON  [dbo].[tbl_pvporderview]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  Merge killer as k
  Using (select serial, [kill] from inserted) as I (serial, [kill])
  On (k.serial = I.serial)
  When matched then
   Update set [kill] = I.[kill]
   When not matched then
   Insert (serial, [kill]) values (I.serial, I.[kill]);
END
```

Comment: then i woudl still have to compare the values it wants to enter with existign ones, so my trigger would run only if specific column gets updated IF 
    (UPDATE([Kill]))

Comment: Could you give more detail in your question please? I really don't understand what you are trying to do that cannot be accomplished by using a combination of the INSERTED/DELETED tables or by using a BEFORE and a AFTER trigger.

Comment: the problem with my trigger above is that it will only insert - however i need a "exist" check first and update if a serial  in the table its writing to, exists already (the serial in killer table is a primary key).

Comment: The trigger works - however due to the primary key, i cant insert duplicates so i need to update if it already exists. But im not sure how to set up the UPDATE [Kill] WHERE serial = xxxx - i cant use i.serial here (a multi-part error)

Comment: Does the one above work?

Comment: the one above seems to insert only if  ON i.serial = k.serial;
 but that woudl end up wit ha  error since i cant enter duplicate primary keys. So i need it to insert a new one if it doesnt exist and update if it does exist.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense now. Altered trigger based on your requirements.

Comment: ok but now that eliminates the primary key violation issue, however it wont update the killer table if the serial already exists.

Comment: Ok the above should meet your requirements now ;-)

Comment: that should do indeed, i simply added IF (UPDATE([Kill]))
BEGIN  to limit the trigger from doing extra unneeded work and only run it if the KILL was actually updated (not when some other column got updated in the table).